# Visual Studio 2015, xmmintrin.h cannot find malloc.h

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile a C++ project that is using xmmintrin.h. I am aware the CRT has been moved to windows kit for vs 2015. I have included the CRT in additional directories. However since xmmintrin.h is in the standard vc include path (where iostream is located), and the CRT has been moved I have failed to get the two paths to see each other.

Anyway way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to do this in the VS GUI, but somewhere in the project properties you'll have "Include Paths". These paths are passed with a `/I` to `cl.exe`.

What you want to do is add the path to xmmintrin.h to the end of these paths. This means that that directory will be searched last, so any headers that exist in the regular CRT will be given priority. And only if you don't have the header in CRT, your local paths, etc, will it search here. That should avoid any conflicts.

A dirtier solution would be to just create a copy of that file (and it's few dependencies) somewhere else and include from there.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't work but the dirty approach gave me an idea. I made temp changes to the source using absolute paths. That worked, and it's only a library I am building so it is a good one and time fix. A permanent solution would be nice though.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue, after spending hours on trying to install missing libs, packages, sdk's, ... The solution was to uninstall visual studio 2010, then delete the visual studio 2010 installation folder, then delete the VS 2010 registry keys. Only after having removed all these, I installed visual studio 2010 back on again, and I got all the .h and other files that were missing back on. Hooray.

Regards,